# Single and Double Quotes Auto-Switching

Tags: python, string

I am having a simple issue with python swapping quotes types (single and double) on me automatically. Because of it I can't get back to the original text.

Here is an example

```
s1 = ('foo\'bar' , 'bar\"foo', 'dead\'\"beef', 'beef\\\'\"dead')
s2 = unicode(s1)
print repr(s2)
>>>u'("foo\'bar", \'bar"foo\', \'dead\\\'"beef\', \'beef\\\\\\\'"dead\')'
```

In this example python did an auto-swap of quote types for the first element of the tuple. Of course this was expected since only single quotes appeared in the string. The issue I have is I am trying to read a file which is of the format exactly like the printed value above including the u, starting quote, and trailing quote. Is there a way to read the file and return back to the original s1 tuple. Actually, I don't even need the tuple just the strings inside. No encoding/decoding scheme I have found works properly because of the auto-swapping. Of course I can write a regex or function to solve this but there must be a python way of doing this. Also pickling or any other serialization is not a solution for me.

thanks in advance

Comment: The single and double quotes are syntactically identical in Python. That a string is represented with one quote and not the other, is ultimately inconsequential

Comment: Can you motivate the need to preserve these quote differences?

Comment: What are you doing with the tuples and strings you're reading from the file?

Comment: `unicode` expects a sting. you provide a tuple (`s1`). So under the hood `unicode` probably calls `str` on the tuple to get a string representation of it. So couln't you do `s2 = u', '.join([unicode(i) for i in s1])` instead?

Comment: "Of course I can write a regex or function to solve this but there must be a python way of doing this."  -- why not write a regex or function and post it, so that it's clear to us what functionality you want?

Comment: That's a very odd file format. How is the file created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the issue of quotes for a moment, let's concentrate on your real need:

> > to read a file which is of the format exactly like the printed value above including the u, starting quote, and trailing quote. ... Actually, I don't even need the tuple just the strings inside

If you have a file, the contents of which look like so:

```
u'("foo\'bar", \'bar"foo\', \'dead\\\'"beef\', \'beef\\\\\\\'"dead\')'
```

The following program will give you access to the strings inside:

```
import ast
with open('x.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        strings = ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(line))
        # You can do whatever you want with the `strings` var, e.g:
        assert(strings[0] == "foo'bar")
        assert(strings[0] == 'foo\'bar')
        print strings[0]
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me what you want, but I wrote a script `test.py` with two potential solutions, one of which is @hitzg's:

```
# @hitzg's solution:
s1 = ('foo\'bar', 'bar\"foo', 'dead\'\"beef', 'beef\\\'\"dead')
s2 = u', '.join([unicode(i) for i in s1])
print repr(s2)

# My tweak, in case that's not quite what you want:
s1 = ("'foo\'bar'", "'bar\"foo'", "'dead\'\"beef'", "'beef\\\'\"dead'")
s2 = u', '.join([unicode(i) for i in s1])
print repr(s2)
```

Here is the output of this script:

```
In [5]: run test.py
u'foo\'bar, bar"foo, dead\'"beef, beef\\\'"dead'
u'\'foo\'bar\', \'bar"foo\', \'dead\'"beef\', \'beef\\\'"dead\''
```

Does either of these methods give you what you want?  If not, can you explain how they differ from what you want?  That might clarify things such that we can give you a better answer.